# Winrar-like archive utility for OS X

Tags: macos, mac, compression, archiving

I've been a Mac user for about 1.5 years and so far enjoyed the experience. But one thing I miss from other operating systems is the lack of compression/decompression utilities that follow the "folder" analogy.

The things I was able to find only decompressed entire archives to a destination directory without even giving me the chance to see what's contained in the archive. I guess I am more used to something like winrar or the gnome archive utility so when I double click an archive file, I wan't to be able to see what's contained in it and be able to extract individual files.

Is there any hope (without resorting to command line), or maybe I should code one myself :)

Comment: I get annoyed on Windows because when I double click a zip file I expect it to extract everything into my current folder.  Double clicking shows me the contents like a folder which is useless because I can't use the files without extracting them from the archive.

Instead I have to right click to extract and then it puts up three dialog boxes that I never change to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [BetterZip Quick Look Generator](http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator) would work. It doesn't make it transparent like a folder, but it's fairly fast at displaying the contents of the archive.

[image: BetterZip]

Answer (score 4):

try [Zipeg](http://www.zipeg.com/)

very nice app for inspecting/unarchiving archives - and it's free.

Comment: Zipeg development halted in July 2012... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipeg

Answer (score 1):

[iArchiver](http://creativebe.com/iarchiver/) provides a file-explorer type interface for archives.  However, it does this when you drag the archive on to the "Extract" box in the program; just double-clicking archives in Finder will still auto-extract them.

Answer (score 0):

[Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/) can do this.

> Springy is a simple to use, yet
>   powerful archiving and compression
>   utility for Mac OS X. Springy
>   integrates seamlessly with the Finder
>   and includes some very useful
>   features. All archiving tasks can be
>   done via Drag and Drop, system
>   Services Menu or through Springy's
>   Finder contextual menu.Springy
>   features at a glance: **Open and browse
>   the contents of an archive or disk
>   image without extracting any file from
>   it.** Quickly extract all files or only
>   files of choice from an archive or
>   disk image. Quickly extract the whole
>   archive or disk image by
>   double-clicking its file in a
>   Finder.Modify the contents of an
>   existing archive or disk image: add,
>   overwrite, delete and rename files in
>   an archive or disk image. Full Drag &
>   Drop support for archiving and
>   extracting from and into Finder.

[image]

The context menu:

[image]

Springy is shareware, try it before you buy it ($19.95 for a license).

Answer (score 0):

RarLab provides a windows version which is called WinRar **and one for Mac OS X** just called RAR.

The download including a 40days trial can be found here:
http://www.rarsoft.com/download.htm

Comment: AFAIK RAR is just a command-line tool; the poster is looking for a graphical explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using macPar DeLuxe as it handles par files and rar files.  Feature light, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness (of a list of nice archivers) and just citing [another similar question's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/101483/expand-rars-like-other-archives-zip-bzip-gzip-c/102115#102115), **you can try [Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)** (which I'm still to experiment myself).

I have same exact wish as the OP, and I just had a [very bad experience](https://superuser.com/questions/116127/problems-running-some-apps-on-mac-no-error-message/116211#116211) with [Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/), which was the best one I've tried so far.

Comment: Unarchiver just takes an archive and uncompress it. You can't view the contents before that...

Comment: fair enough @maxxyme but i think i did acknowledge that in the answer. in any case, this is 11 years old, and i don't use mac for at least 4. i still recommend trying 7-zip. cheers!

Comment: I like 7-zip too (using it on Windows for years - can't remember when I started by the way) ... but I'm still looking for something similar on Mac...

Answer (score 0):

[UnrarX](http://unrarx.sourceforge.net/) is very basic but it works, and it is free (open-source).

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party, but I recommend Marta if you don't want to mess with system extensions

https://marta.sh/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please discuss its pros and cons

Answer (score -1):

"[The Unarchiver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJmYuUuN_sAhU-AGMBHbbEDMwQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.apple.com%2Ffr%2Fapp%2Fthe-unarchiver%2Fid425424353%3Fmt%3D12&usg=AOvVaw1SpQp8wVEUyvtSM11OTHYu)"! is free and located in the Mac App Store. It can extract almost all archives.

Comment: OP asked for a "Winrar-like archive utility", that would let him preview the contents of the archive BEFORE uncompressing it!!!