# Expand rars like other archives (zip, bzip, gzip, &c)

Tags: macos, archiving, rar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good way to extract .rar files on the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac)

What (free) program will allow me to double click on a rar and have it just expand everything into a folder, the way it does when I open a zip, or nearly any other kind of archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) is free and acts in much the same way as the built in decompresser. And it's got a lovely set of icons.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I'm aware of that opens it transparently like a folder is [Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/), although it isn't free (but very well priced at $19.95):

[image]