# Problems running some apps on mac, no error message

Tags: macos, mac

I hope this question is within superuser scope.

I've recently downloaded an application **that just happens to be a computer game** but this is not pertinent to the problem.
Thing is, I can't run any of them on my mac, and I have no idea why. Whenever I try to open them, they seem to open and close too quickly to see anything happen. **No error messages at all**.

I've tried even rebooting my mac. I have never had other similar issue whatsoever.

I've got a new macbook pro with OSX 10.6.2 and quite a lot of apps, but none that I can imagine would conflict with this.

---

I'm hoping to find two kind of answers here:

How can I track this problem down? Someone more experienced with mac may know this.

Maybe someone have had the same issue and got a word about it?

Comment: I've had a similar problem with the installer for the original Starcraft - never found a solution though.

Comment: @trolle Never? You just gave up, then? I'm talking to Blizzard support, but they take their time and I'm still trying to make them understand the issue. Next time I'll just post a link to here.

Comment: Questions related to computer games tend to be closed, so I edited it a bit to make it more generic.

Comment: yeah, I just gave up -  it was right after Snow Leopard came out, and I figured Blizzard would update their installer. Never got around to trying again ;-)

Comment: @trolle, I won't give up. I'll make this work. You can check on later for the answer here, eventually. By the way, thanks @Nifle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's how I've managed to solve my issue:**

```
$ chmod +x SystemCheck_enUS.app/Contents/MacOS/BlizzardSystemCheck
```

**And here's why that happened:**

For [many reasons](http://vark.com/t/3da885), I started trying a great extraction tool (apparently highly [advised](https://superuser.com/questions/99911/winrar-like-archive-utility-for-os-x) by [John T](https://superuser.com/users/1931/john-t)) called [springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/). Apparently it did a bad job with keeping the permissions while extracting the ZIP file I've downloaded from Blizzard. I'm already looking for yet another solution.

That's all.

Comment: Maybe file a bug report to the Springy developer.  I think if you read his blog, you might change your tune.

Comment: @churnd I like my tune and see no problem with it. I meant if such a basic issue was within springy I want to avoid other possible issues and look else where for what I needed to do. I don't need the ultimate tool for extracting, just basic stuff that should be built-in the OS. - maybe the problem was that I assumed springy was that, and it isn't. **My fault**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I had the exact same problem with exactly the same app (Battle.net beta profile app), and the solution was to unpack the archive using the default Archive Utility, and not another app (which was Keka in my case).

Comment: @n1313 wow, over 3 years later! I'm glad to know this still helps someone. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check the `Console` to see if there are any error messages.

If it says something like "Permission Denied" then you may have to [repair permissions](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aoxn.html).

> Mac OS X assigns specific access privileges, known as permissions, to all of your programs, folders, and documents. These permissions are usually managed automatically, but when a permissions error occurs, it can cause significant problems. For example, your applications may not launch, or your computer might respond slowly. These problems are more likely to occur after you update your operating system or install new software.
>
> To improve your system's performance, use the permissions repair function in Disk Utility:
>
> 1. To open Disk Utility, from the Applications  folder, open Utilities, and then double-click the Disk Utility icon.
> 2. In the column on the left, click your startup disk.
> 3. Click the First Aid tab, and then click Repair Disk Permissions. Disk Utility will reset any files and folders with incorrect settings.
>
> Note: If a third-party application has permissions errors and did not use Apple's installer, a permissions repair may not fix everything. If you follow the steps above, and your application still does not launch, you may need to remove and reinstall the problematic applications. For more information on removing applications in Mac OS X, see [In Mac OS X, how do I remove an application](http://kb.iu.edu/data/adke.html)?
>
> For more information about how permissions work in Mac OS X, see [Troubleshooting permissions issues in Mac OS X in Apple's knowledge base](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963?viewlocale=en_US).

Comment: D'oh, I should have thought of that... It says "Permission denied". Would you happen to know how to "fix" it while I do my research? I can only think of using sudo on the terminal.

Comment: Just adding that the sudo command did no good. I used *sudo open SystemCheck_enUS.app* and it returned:
*LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/caue/Downloads/SystemCheck_enUS.app* - I'm not expecting you to know what that is, just reporting here.

Comment: Nope. Repair Permissions repaired just one random file at /usr/share/derby and nothing else. So, unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue as I expected (because I had already checked it with chmod).

Comment: That permission repair from Apple will only repair permissions known by apple, which sums up to things installed through Installer besides things from the system. I just read that on the KB: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452?viewlocale=en_US
So neither of you guys should expect this to work in my case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an administrator account?  (The console saying "Permission denied" often indicates that you don't).  If you do, you can try to fix permissions.  In Utilities, run Disk Utility, select your hard drive, and tell it to repair permissions.

The file you want to look at is the system.log.  If the console is not working for you, here are two alternatives:

In Terminal (also located in Utilities), typing in

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

should let you watch as messages are written to the system log.  If you then run your game, *cough*, app :) any error messages should appear there.

If you have [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/) on your computer, open it up and choose "File -> Open File By Name" and type in /var/log/system.log.  This'll let you see the entire system log, and will prompt you to authenticate if needed.

Comment: Yes, sure I do have - you could see that from my second comment on Josh's answer. I'm trying to fix permissions now. By the way, would you happen to if there's a way to use sudo on finder rather than on terminal?

Comment: @Cawas On Finder?  A program called (Snow) Leopard Cache Cleaner has a nice option to run the Finder as root.  As for running other GUI applications as root (I don't know if it applies to the Finder), see http://serverfault.com/questions/47141/is-it-possible-to-run-an-os-x-gui-app-as-root/47903#47903

Comment: yeah, I was hoping for something like gksudo (from gnome) and that could be added as a Service (right mouse click) or something like that. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Cawas Well, then, I was going to suggest Pseudo, but I see you've found it.  Nice to know it works on Snow Leopard.