# Starting Dropbox on OS X through SSH without needing to log in to desktop

Tags: macos, ssh, dropbox

Is there a way to start the Dropbox syncing client through SSH?

I already have the desktop version of Dropbox installed. However, I am using SSH to connect to the machine and if I restart the computer, Dropbox does not restart unless I log in to the Desktop.

Can I avoid the overhead required to log into the desktop and just start the Dropbox client from the command line?

Running `open -a Dropbox.app` fails with code: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Dropbox.app with error -10810.`

I am aware of the [Dropbox CLI](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI), however it just seemed like it was silly to need to install additional software to start the client that is already installed. Perhaps it is the only way.

Comment: have you tried touching some files in the Dropbox folder?

Comment: I've never used it, but perhaps this will help: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI

Comment: So Dropbox is already installed via the regular GUI installer. If I connect to the computer via SSH *without* logging in through the GUI login window first, the Dropbox client appears to not start. If I add files or touch files in the Dropbox folder, they do not get synced. I would like to avoid installing the CLI if I can, just because the normal Dropbox client is already installed on there, and it is much easier to configure.

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102105/1174

Answer (score 2):

One thought is the [Dropbox CLI](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI)

Another - hopefully just so simple you hadn't thought to try it - would be to launch to GUI client from the command line: `open -a "Dropbox.app"`. Syncing happens automatically on launch.

Comment: I gave that a shot and received this error: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Dropbox.app with error -10810.`

Comment: Frustrating! I can't replicate this error, but some googling suggests that it may be a permissions error. Try running `tail -f /var/log/system.log` and seeing what Dropbox.app errors appear. You should then be able to add execute permissions as appropriate. <http://superuser.com/questions/116127/problems-running-some-apps-on-mac-no-error-message> and <https://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/osx_x86_64_minecraft_execution_fixed>

Comment: The Dropbox CLI does not appear to support OS X, at least not for me on Mountain Lion... status says daemon is not installed, trying to install yields "Error: Platform not supported"

Comment: Launching the GUI over the CLI works just fine for me (on Mavericks). +1.

Comment: I have the same issue with @user1027169, it just won't start.

Comment: @jona as of 10.10.5 (Yosemite) attempting to run `./dropbox.py start` requires me to use the "-i" option to install the daemon, and when I try *that* it throws an exception with "Error: Platform not supported"