# Recommend archiver software on OSX

Tags: macos, software-rec, archiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good way to extract .rar files on the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac)

Please recommend a nice software which will work on Lion. Default one is extracting immediately after I double click and does not support RAR, which is essential.

Would be nice if software can first browse the archive and then let me extract it.

Commercial software recommendations are mostly welcomed.

Comment: Please show which programs you already tried (it's really *not* difficult to find some) and found lacking; i.e. research effort.

Comment: Archive Utility.

Comment: (Closely) related to [osx - What’s a good way to extract .rar files on the Mac? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac)

Comment: I wasn't actually advocating to close this question. The linked question was specific to RAR files. This one is possibly even closer to [osx - Winrar-like archive utility for OS X - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/99911/winrar-like-archive-utility-for-os-x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zipeg](http://www.zipeg.com/) is free and it seems like a good choice for you. Here is a summary of the features from their website:

> ✓ popular: .zip, .rar, .7z, .tar, .gz, .tgz, .bzip2, .iso, .cbr, .cbz formats;
>
> ✓ rare: .arj, .lha .lzh, .cpio, .rpm, .chm, .z, .war, .ear
>
> ✓ decrypts password protected .zip and .rar files (strong AES
> encryption).
>
> ✓ auto-magically combines and opens multipart .zip and
> .rar files.
>
> ✓ shows content of archive and allow you to select what to
> extract.

Answer (score 1):

#### [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)

It doesn't support looking inside archives, but it's free, simple enough and works with tons of formats.

[image: the unarchiver]

Comment: I would prefer something that will browse first, like Winrar with GUI

Answer (score 1):

[BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) and [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) look like what you're interested in.

Comment: *> Pacifist is not yet compatible with Mac OS X 10.7 “Lion”* though

Comment: Thanks @slhck. I spent about as long to research for this as the OP, searching for "zip" on iusethis ;)

Comment: A strong vote for BetterZip, IMO substantially better UI and usabiity than the free alternatives justify the price...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/).

The list of supported archive and disk image types includes ZIP, TAR, RAR, 7-ZIP, TGZ, TBZ, PAX, CPIO, CPGZ, JAR, SIT, DMG, ISO... and more. Future releases will include more types in this list. Also allows you to browse archives before extracting them.

Comment: Thanks Mahendru, will try. Looking forward to see other opinions and recommendations.